# Live Expressions in Safari Debugger

Tags: debugging, mobile, safari

Is there a way to do Live Expressions in the Safari Debugger? I need to do exactly what is explained in this article, but in Safari.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/accessibility/focus/

I know about Safari's watch expressions, but those don't seem to update as I interact with the DOM and clicking the refresh button on the watch expression takes away the focus from DOM elements.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing, this workaround was good enough for my use case. In the Safari console:

```js
window.intv = setInterval(() => {
  if (window.curEl !== document.activeElement) {
    window.curEl = document.activeElement;
    console.log(document.activeElement);
  }
}, 100);

// when you're done
clearInterval(window.intv);
```